# invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++

I'm using `gcc` on codeblocks and I'd like to write a function that uses an array of records.

However I keep getting the error:

```
invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct rendeles {
    string nev;
int mennyiseg;
};

struct teaceg {
string nev;
int mennyiseg;
};

int szam; 
struct rendeles rendelt [100];      
struct teaceg cegek [100];          
int h;

int hanyadikceg (string cegnev)
{                            
    for (int i=0;i<szam;i++)
    {
        if (cegek[i].nev==cegnev)
            {
                return i;
            }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hány db rendelés lesz összesen?";
    cin >> szam;
    if (szam > 100)
    {
        cout << "Hiba: túl nagy a rendelések száma! (100 a maximum)";
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<szam;i++)        
    {
        cout << "A(z) " << i+1 <<". cég neve:";
        cin >> rendelt[i].nev;                                 
        cout << "A(z) " << i+1 <<". rendelés mennyisége:";
        cin >> rendelt[i].mennyiseg;                           
    }
    cout << endl;

    h = hanyadikceg('Lipton');              //the problem is in this line
    cout << "Hanyadik cég a xyz:" << h;

    for (int i=0;i<szam;i++)          
    {
        cout << "A(z) " << i+1 << ". rendelés: " << rendelt[i].nev << " " <<     rendelt[i].mennyiseg << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What causes this error?

Comment: btw: having function and variable names in the lingua franca of programming makes it far easier to get help, since far more people are able to understand the code.

Comment: Just curious, what language is that (I can't tell)?

Comment: @Jesse, I believe it is Hungarian.

Comment: @Jesse: google translate autodetection claims it is hungarian.

Comment: Yes, it's Hungarian. I wrote it in this language, because it was a school assignment, and we used all variables in Hungarian. But I know it's better to use English for most purposes.

Btw, I don't know how this became a "famous question"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use double-quotes (`"`) for string literals, not single-quotes (`'`).

Answer (score 4):

You are using single quotes (`'Lipton'`).  Single quotes are for `char`-literals.

Use `"Lipton"`, for a `const char*` literal.

Answer (score 4):

Change `'Lipton'` to `"Lipton"` in the problem line and the compilation error will go away.

In C/C++, double-quoted expressions are strings (or, technically, *string literals*) and resolve to `char *` or `const char *` type, while single-quoted expressions are characters (or *character literals*) and resolve to `char` type (which can be implicitly casted to `int`). That explains your error: the compiler cannot convert the `char` integer type to the `const char *` that the function signature requires.

Comment: Just a note.  String literals are *always* resolved to `const`.

Comment: String literals in C++ have type `const char[N]`, where N is the length of the string including nul terminator. There's an implicit conversion to `const char*`, and in C++03 there's a deprecated conversion to `char*` for compatibility with C. IIRC, the deprecated conversion is removed in C++11. The function `hanyadikceg` calls for a `std::string`, and there's another implicit conversion from `const char*` to `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

```
h = hanyadikceg('Lipton');
```

should be

```
h = hanyadikceg("Lipton");
```