# populating array of strings a for loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I want to populate an array of strings with the help of for loop and print them

```
string R_name[3] = {""};

for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
    R_name[i] = 'Small';
    cout<<R_name[j]<<" "<< endl;
}
```

It gives me the error: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
And prints

```
l
l
l 
?
```

Comment: Did you mean `"Small"` (string literal), not `'Small'` (multi-character literal)?

Comment: `'Small'` tells the compiler that you want a character five characters long. You probably want `"Small"`.

Comment: Also, for your sanity, use `std::array<std::string, 3> R_name;`.

Comment: Reasonably close duplicate of [invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9702506/1563833) and probably best explained by [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 0):

You have accidentally used a *multi-character literal* instead of a *string literal* by using single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`.

- `'Small'` : Multi-character literal
- `"Small"` : String literal

It's *non-standard*, but for those compilers that support it, when you assign a *multi-character literal* like `'Small'` to a `std::string`, even though it's legal, you should still get a multitude of warnings including possibly:

- character constant too long for its type

  - (when you use more than 4 characters, because it typically interprets each character as a byte and is trying to fit it into an `int`)
- overflow in conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 'nnnnnnn' to ''c''

  - (because it's trying to choose a type to assign to your string, and chooses `char`, which is typically not as large as `int`, so there's overflow.)

The solution, in your case, is to change `'Small'` to `"Small"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   string R_name[3] = {""};

for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
    R_name[i] = "Small";
    cout<<R_name[i]<<" "<< endl;
}
```

In this way you can populate array of string and print it.